# Use table variable in Lua class

Tags: class, oop, lua, lua-table

I need a table variable in a Lua class, which is unique for each instance of the class.
In the example listed below the variable self.element seems to be a static variable, that is used by all class instances.

How do I have to change the testClass to get a non static self.element table variable?

Example:

```
  local testClass ={dataSize=0, elementSize=0, element = {} }

  function testClass:new (data)
   local o = {}
   setmetatable(o, self)
   self.__index = self

   -- table to store the parts of the element
   self.element = {}
   -- data
   self.element[1] = data
   -- elementDataSize
   self.elementSize = #data
 
   return o
  end

  function testClass:getSize()
    return self.elementSize
  end


  function testClass:addElement(data)
    -- add data to element
    self.element[#self.element+1] = data
    self.elementSize = self.elementSize + #data
  end
  
 function testClass:printElement(element)
    -- print elements data
    element = element or self.element
    local content = ""
    for i=1, #element do
        content = content .." " .. tostring(element[i])
    end
    print("Elements: " .. content)
end

function printAll(element)
  print("Size: " .. tostring(element:getSize()))
  element:printElement()
 end
  
  test = testClass:new("E1")
  printAll(test)
  test:addElement("a")
  printAll(test)
  
  test2 = testClass:new("E2")
  printAll(test2)
  test2:addElement("cde")
  printAll(test2)
  print("............")
  printAll(test)
```

This implementation returns:

```
$lua main.lua
Size: 2
Elements:  E1
Size: 3
Elements:  E1 a
Size: 2
Elements:  E2
Size: 5
Elements:  E2 cde
............
Size: 3
Elements:  E2 cde
```

For the last output I need

```
Size: 3

Elements:  E1 a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a common mistake in your `:new` function.

You assign `self.element` but this should be `o.element`. `self` in this function refers to the `testClass` table not to the object you are creating. To make `element` unique to each object you need to assign it to `o`, the object being created.

```
  function testClass:new (data)
   local o = {}
   setmetatable(o, self)
   self.__index = self

   -- table to store the parts of the element
   o.element = {}
   -- data
   o.element[1] = data
   -- elementDataSize
   o.elementSize = #data
 
   return o
  end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! This works. What confuses me is that self.elementSize seems to work as it contains the length of the elements for each instance

Comment: if all the results happen to be the same length it would appear that way, or if you are referencing it before any other instances are created

Answer (score 2):

In `testClass:new()` `self` refers to `testClass`.

```
local test = testClass:new()
```

`test.element` will refer to `testClass.element`

Your instance is `o`, so when you want each instance to have its own `element` replace `self.element = {}` with `o.element = {}`