# How can I store layer information within a Layer table

Tags: oop, lua, lua-table

I just started learning Lua (5.4) and I wanted to OOP a Neural Network (I have done it in Python before). However, when I tested my Layer "class" I had some strange results. My table has the same content for every "row" within the table.
My code is as follows:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
  

-- Creates random value between lower and upper bounds
-- the function could be better, but it works good enough for this
local function randbetween(lower_limit, upper_limit)
    local treshold = 0.5
    local value = math.random()
    if value < treshold then return math.random() * lower_limit
    elseif value >= treshold then return math.random() * upper_limit end
end

-- A single Neuron within a neural network
local Neuron = {}

function Neuron:init(numberOfInputs)
    self.numberOfInputs = numberOfInputs
    self.weights = {}
    for i = 1,numberOfInputs,1 do self.weights[i] = randbetween(-1, 1) end
    self.bias = randbetween(-1,1)
    return self
end

-- A single layer within the neural network
local Layer = {}

function Layer:init(numberOfNeurons, numberOfInputsPerNeuron)
    self.numberOfNeurons = numberOfNeurons
    self.neurons = {}
    for i = 1,numberOfInputsPerNeuron,1 do
        self.neurons[i] = Neuron:init(numberOfInputsPerNeuron)
    end
    return self
end

local L = {}

L[1] = Layer:init(2,0)
L[2] = Layer:init(3, 2)
for k,v in pairs(L) do print(k,v) end
```

This is my output:

```
1   table: 000002AB12D5D7D0
2   table: 000002AB12D5D7D0
```

L[1] should have numberOfNeurons = 2, so I expect something in the line of this:

```
init    function: 000001E022968760
neurons table: 000001E02297D6E0
numberOfNeurons 2
```

However, it returns:

```
init    function: 000001E022968760
neurons table: 000001E02297D6E0
numberOfNeurons 3
```

Which is identical to L[2].

This leads me to believe that all the table rows are overwritten by the last entry.

Is there any way to fix this or am I doing something wrong? I suspect that this occurs because I don't use metatables, but I don't know if that's the problem.

Comment: your `init` function should create a new object, `self` in that scope refers to the table `Layer` not a unique object. this Q&A might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561981/use-table-variable-in-lua-class

Comment: @Nifim thank you for linking to that Q&A. It fixed my issue.